# Internet fully disconnects when I try to authenticate in some sites. What could it be?

Tags: networking, router, internet, authentication

I have noticed that when I try to log in some sites, my internet completely shuts down.

One of those sites is Outlook.com. When the mail animation is running, before loading the form login, I got disconnected.

Another site I noticed it. It has 2 screens login, the first one asks only for the username. After that, just before it loads the second screen where it asks for the password, my internet goes off too.

I feel like it something related to handshake or anti-bot track system as it seems to be related to authentication.

How do prevent this?

Where is the problem could be? My PC, my provider, my modem/ router? I have discarded the websites for now.

How to gather more information?

My setup:
It is optic fiber internet. It connects to a small box that connects to a router. This router share connection by wifi and cable. I'm using Windows 10 connected by cable to this router.

I confirm only the router disconnects. All the router LEDs indicator turn off, except the power one. The first box, which connects the fiber cable does not reset.

Comment: How have you determined the internet connection is lost? Is it only on the Win 10 PC, or also on other devices connected to the router? I.E., is the connection being lost at the router (they *can* be infected by malware, for example, https://www.cyberghostvpn.com/en_US/privacyhub/router-malware/), so that other devices are disconnected, as well, or on the PC? If at the router, I'd be concerned about a man-in-the-middle attack.

Comment: Also look at Windows Defender Smart Screen to see if it is blocking anything.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I determined because all the router LEDs indicator turn off, except the power one. Those which turns off are the LAN, WAN and Internet. I have made some test now, the modem (first box which connects the fiber optics does not turn off). I will investigate your link, thank you!

Comment: @John thank you John, I will check that too!

Comment: so to me it really sounds like your router is malfunctioning, and needs replaced.

Comment: @FrankThomas thank you. Yes, it looks so. I wonder how it was even possible that accessing an website would disconnect my internet.